# Raising events in a class library exposed to COM

Tags: vb.net, com, vb6, interop

I'm trying to write a wrapper to a service, which will be used by an existing VB6 project. I've got most of the basic framework working, except for one important aspect: I can reference the wrapper in a VB6 project and subs/function calls etc. work as expected, but events do not. The events are visible in the VB6 app, but they never fire.

VB.NET Code:

```
Public Event Action_Response(ByVal Status as String)
Public Function TestEvent()
    RaiseEvent Action_Response("Test Done")
    Return "Done"
End Function
```

VB6 Code:

```
Dim WithEvents my_Wrapper as Wrapper_Class
Private Sub cmdTest_Click()
    Set my_Wrapper = New Wrapper_Class
    Debug.Print my_Wrapper.TestEvent() 
End Sub

Private Sub my_Wrapper_Action_Response(ByVal Status As String)
    Debug.Print Status
    Set my_Wrapper = Nothing
End Sub
```

So, the cmdTest button code prints 'Done' as expected, but the Action_Response event doesn't fire. Is there something else do I need to do to get the event to fire?

Comment: Document how you made your VB.NET class `<ComVisible>`

Comment: @Hans: I created the class library project, deleted the default class then added a New Item and picked 'COM Class' from the options.

Comment: I had to make direct use of <ComSourceInterfaces(GetType({eventinterface}))> to get events to work properly. I +though+ <COMVISIBLE> would do it automatically, but it doesn't seem to work that way.

Comment: @drventure: Please could you elaborate on how to use that in vb.net? Please bear in mind that I am a .net novice, so I am not familiar with much of the terminology.

Comment: Okay, I found [this article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd8bf0x3%28v=VS.100%29.aspx), but I'm struggling to follow it. Specifically, the part where the ComSourceInterfaces attribute is applied to the class. See the class I'm using already has the ComClass attribute applied to it--that was put there automatically by VB when I added it as a COM class--and it would seem that I can't have both attributes applied to the class. Can anyone please explain what I need to do?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its too much to write in a comment, so I'll make it an answer....

First, identify the .net class you want to expose to COM. I'll pick a class called CORE.

Create an interface that describes the EVENTS that the CORE object will source (ie generate).

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("some guid here...use guidgen, I'll call it GUID1")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)> _
Public Interface ICoreEvents
    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.DispId(1)> _
    Sub FileLoaded(ByVal Message As String)
End Interface
```

Next, Create an interface for the COM exposed properties and methods of your class.

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<Guid("another GUID, I'll call it guid2")> _
<InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual)> _
Public Interface ICore
    ReadOnly Property Property1() As Boolean
    ReadOnly Property AnotherProperty() As ISettings
    ReadOnly Property Name() As String
    ReadOnly Property Phone() As String
End Interface
```

Now, create your actual .net class

```
<ComVisible(True)> _
<ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)> _
<ComDefaultInterface(GetType(ICore))> _
<ComSourceInterfaces(GetType(ICoreEvents))> _
<Guid("a third GUID, I'll call it GUID3")> _
Public Class Core
    Implements ICore

    <System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisible(False)> _
    Public Delegate Sub OnFileLoaded(ByVal Message As String)
    Public Event FileLoaded As OnFileLoaded
End Class
```

Now, when you need to raise the FileLoaded event, just RAISEEVENT FILELOADED(Message) from within your class. .NET will forward the event out to COM because you've hooked up the COMSourceInterfaces attribute.

The  attribute is shorthand for much of of this, but unfortunately doesn't give you quite the control that you need to do certain things (for instance retain version compatibility on your com interfaces).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I've created a new project to test it. Unfortunately, there seems to be a problem: The "Implements ICore" line is raising errors for the properties--Class 'Core' must implement 'ReadOnly Property Name As String' for interface 'ICore'. Implementing property must have matching 'ReadOnly' or 'WriteOnly' specifiers. I've tried a few things myself but no obvious solution is springing out at me.

Comment: I'm nearly there I think, drventure. Because I'd copied and pasted your code VB hadn't created the corresponding properties in the Core class--I just had to hit return on the Implements line and that solved that problem. D'oh!

Comment: Now, I've built the class and registered it with a tlb file using regasm. The class is showing up in a VB6 test project and everything looks okay as far as the events, methods and properties are concerned--they're all showing up correctly in the IDE--but as soon as I try to create a new instance of the class I'm getting an automation error: "The system cannot find the file specified." Which seems odd as there doesn't seem to be any files being referred to anywhere in code.

Comment: I don't know if this will help, but when I try to inspect the class in OleView I'm getting this error if I try to expand the tree:  

CoGetCiassObject failed.  
The system cannot find the file specified. 
severity SEVERITY_ERROR, facil4 FACILITY_W1N32 (580070002)

Comment: Okay, I've got it working! I had to use the /codebase switch with Regasm. I understand that's not the ideal way to do this, so I'll have to look into how to do it the proper way now, strong types etc. Phew! And I thought .NET was supposed to make things easier! :-)   


Anyway, thank you very much for your help drventure, it's been invaluable.

Comment: @drventure  This is a _VERY_ helpful answer.  Reading examples is definitely the way to get nuances like ComSourceInterfaces and InterfaceIsIDispatch right.  I now have my events useable in COM, exposed alongside my methods.  One note, for reasons I am not clear on, using Regasm to build my .tlb file did not export the events or the event interface.  Switching to Tlbexp caused the events to show up right.

Comment: @drventure However there is still something about the type library event interface that VB does not like, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23959034/withevents-error-sinking-a-com-event-that-comes-from-a-net-component