# Calling VB6 functions in a VB6 EXE file from a VB.NET form in a VB.NET DLL

Tags: .net, vb.net, vb6

I have a VB6 program. From that VB6, I'm accessing a VB.NET DLL to launch a VB.NET form. Is there any way for me to click a button on the VB.NET form and have that trigger a function back in the VB6?

Comment: Use a public event, subscribe it in your VB6 code.

Comment: Could you please get me some sample? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your description, your VB.NET DLL must already contain a Com interface that allows you to make calls to it from your VB6 code (search your code for "DispId(1)" as this is required for a com interface). In addition to that you'll need a separate com interface for events (if you don't have it already). These com interface events will allow you to go the other direction (back to VB6) as you desire.

The VB.NET syntax for these two interfaces (one for events, and another for methods and properties) and the class that implements them, is most efficiently shown in full on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4502026/3072580

Once you're back in VB6 and you have access to the object which you're using to make your call into .NET, you'll need to make sure it's declared "WithEvents" (Private WithEvents mobjMyComInterop As InteropNamespace.ComInteropObject) or is an actual control placed on a VB6 form (which is automatically WithEvents). Once this is done you'll be able to select your .NET object from VB6's top left object dropdown and then on the right drop down you'll be able to pick the event...

This will generate a handler in VB6 with a signature like this:

Private Sub mobjMyComInterop_MyEvent(ByVal Message As String)

End Sub